# When do the lights blink?

Tags: code-golf, number

Imagine you have two lights. These lights blink on and off at a specific rate:

```
Light 0: Delay 0ms and then blink every 1000ms
Light 1: Delay 500ms and then blink every 1000ms
```

Let's simulate these lights for the first 2000ms:

```
0ms:    Light 0 on
500ms:  Light 1 on
1000ms: Light 0 off
1500ms: Light 1 off
2000ms: Light 0 on
```

## The challenge

Given a list of ordered pairs representing the timing for lights, write a program or function to output the sequence for when they blink.

#### Input

The input should be in the following format:

```
TimeToSimulate
Light0Delay,Light0Period
Light1Delay,Light1Period
...
```

In this format, the example above would be:

```
2000
0,1000
500,1000
```

#### Output

The output should be a series of ordered triples:

```
Time,LightNum,LightStatus
```

LightStatus is a truthy value if the light turns on and a falsy value if the light turns off.

The output from the above example would be:

```
0,0,True
500,1,True
1000,0,False
1500,1,False
2000,0,True
```

If two lights blink at the same time, the light with the lower number should display first in the output.

#### Other stuff

- The input and output formats aren't strict
- Code shouldn't produce any errors
- The solution shouldn't rely on race conditions
- No standard loopholes
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest solution wins!

#### Test cases

```
Input:

2000
0,1000
500,1000

Output:

0,0,True
500,1,True
1000,0,False
1500,1,False
2000,0,True

----

Input:

2
0,1
0,1

Output:

0,0,True
0,1,True
1,0,False
1,1,False
2,0,True
2,1,True

----

Input:

500
100,50
200,100
300,150

Output:

100,0,True
150,0,False
200,0,True
200,1,True
250,0,False
300,0,True
300,1,False
300,2,True
350,0,False
400,0,True
400,1,True
450,0,False
450,2,False
500,0,True
500,1,False

----

Input:

1000
23,345
65,98
912,12
43,365

Output:

23,0,True
43,3,True
65,1,True
163,1,False
261,1,True
359,1,False
368,0,False
408,3,False
457,1,True
555,1,False
653,1,True
713,0,True
751,1,False
773,3,True
849,1,True
912,2,True
924,2,False
936,2,True
947,1,False
948,2,False
960,2,True
972,2,False
984,2,True
996,2,False
```

## Leaderboard Snippet:

```js
var QUESTION_ID=137465,OVERRIDE_USER=41505;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: How much output is enough?

Comment: @aschepler What do you mean? The input specifies an amount of time to "simulate"

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>98</s> 97 bytes

```
a=>b=>[...Array(a+1)].map((_,i)=>b.map((d,j)=>d[0]--||c.push([i,j,d[d[0]=d[1]-1,2]^=1])),c=[])&&c
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##bVDbboJAEH3fr7CJ0Z2wLBfFVM1qmv6BSZ@AlhVQIRQIoEkjfrudBaJ96CZ7mTPn7MycVF5kHVZJ2eh5EcX3g7hLsdmLjcs5f6sq@UOlZoHPv2VJ6RdLALN9ELEUg8g1fV1v25CX5/pE3YSlLHIVKiLX8nWL2f6nsHwAFgrXh8kkvF9kNWriunmXdVyPxCggtmmaxGSWuhxzeOi4iK3gbnchJgkmmWMqjeKRmbqdgd4J7RmbzR2ycNjylSwtm1k2mSO2cEiwJqp6kpfnBiu7/po8OuF1mSUN3QnD0zUDuinRjI7bTycRa8ITNbxI8xgeLW7jCABr0tFETx6UsjdKsr1ybSv7AgELHoTWhJU6UB8WeV1kMc@KI33@MoiD8fVAJZoK2EOdJWFMLYD/6@j2Vq4QfnmR2nQKKOJN8VGWcaWmpKD9@QF4WiR54OXBLejfFIPx9elJP/AObsjBNu@/)

*Saved a byte thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)* - use currying input syntax.

Comment: Save a byte with currying: `a=>b=>`.

Comment: @Shaggy. You're so fast, I was preparing an edit.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if there are 2 inputs, always curry!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 93 bytes

```python
lambda t,l:sorted(sum([zip(range(x[0],-~t,x[1]),[i]*-~t,[1,0]*t)for i,x in enumerate(l)],[]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYpBCsIwEEX3niLLpIyQVrIRPMl0FpGmGmjTkk6huvDqMbEiboY3/735wfcpNKm/tGmw47WzgmE4L1Nk18llHSU@/SyjDTcnN9QExxfDhjUpQE9V@bAGTRWrforCwyZ8EC6so4uWnRwUAZJSaY4@sOhlA4ga6ryWS@rwE1rr3WXI2ugv/jXmk@QVTEmaPcl0KmRKm1J6Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly11),  <s>26</s>  25 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḣrm⁸ð€µ;€€"J;"J$€€ẎẎḂ0¦€Ṣ
```

A dyadic link taking a list of `delay, period` number-lists and a time-frame number and returning a list of `time, light, action` integers.

The lights are 1-indexed and `0` represents the 'off' action, while `1` represents the 'on' action.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjkVFuY8adxze8KhpzaGt1kASiJS8rJW8VCDsh7v6QGhHk8GhZSDuzkX///@PjjY0MNAxNYjViTYCMoAcIMsYxAKKxf43NTAAAA)**

#### How?

```
Ḣrm⁸ð€µ;€€"J;"J$€€ẎẎḂ0¦€Ṣ - Link: [[delay, period],...], time-frame 
    ð€                    - for €ach [delay, period]:
Ḣ                         -   head (get the delay and modify the item to [period])
 r                        -   inclusive range to time-frame = [delay,delay+1,...,time-frame]
   ⁸                      -   chain's left argument = [period]
  m                       -   modulo slice = [delay, delay+period, delay+2*period, ...]
      µ                   - monadic chain separation, call that v
           J              - range(length(v)) = [1,2,...,nLights]
          "               - zip with:
       ;€€                -   concatenate for €ach for €ach (add light indexes to times)
               $€€        - last two links as a monad for €ach for €ach:
              J           -   range (length(switch-times-for-a-light))
             "            -   zip with:
            ;             -     concatenation (i.e. append a 1-based index)
                  ẎẎ      - tighten & tighten again (flatten by 2 to a list of triples)
                      |€  - sparse application of (for €ach):
                     0    - ...to indexes: 0 (=last entry)
                    Ḃ     - ...action: modulo by 2 (even appended indexes ->0s; odds -> 1s)
                        Ṣ - sort the resulting list of triples
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>206</s> 214 bytes

- Added eight bytes to comply with the rules (taking input via stdin).

```python
Q=input();D,T=Q[0],[map(int,q.split(","))for q in Q[1:]];O,l=[],len(T)
for j in range(l):
	t,b=T[j][0],9>8
	while t<=int(D):O+="%0*d,%0*d,%s"%(len(D),t,len(str(l)),j,b),;b=not b;t+=T[j][1]
print"\n".join(sorted(O))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1Bi4MwEEbP9VeEQCGzHUpia6m62ZN3Eby5OVTqthEbrc6y7K93k@1lePA@3ky/dB9dvK6Vtm76JgF5gbWuGmmweVwmYR3hc79MgyXBkQN8jTN7MutY1ajMmLzEQTcGh86JGqJg@2Dni7t1YoAs2hC2um56E5rpxzna/Nzt0DF69y9JFJCVO8238u2Kr7PwrQi5ApD@uwvNvgTYYwuYt9qNxNqcdq@qMtE0@xL/dHzfj9bvx5m6qygB1lVwJaXkyHh8wMMxCXRKMD0HSFWMKg509PKUcPgD)

This code generates an unordered lists containing each light's switching times, pads those times and the light identifier, sorts said list and outputs it.

Comment: By standard rules you must take input you cannot expect it to pre-exist in a variable. You'll probably find that using `input()` will allow you to cut they byte-count down too (no string parsing will be required since Python 2's `input()` is `eval(raw_input())`) :).

Comment: ...also if you use numbers rather than strings in `O` they'll sort, which would probably also cut the byte count,

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks for noticing the rule discrepency; I will not incorporate your suggestions as there is a significantly shorter Python 2 answer by now.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 106 +  1 (-n) = 107 bytes

```perl
($a[$i],$b[$i++])=eval for<>;for$i(0..$_){for(0..$#a){$a[$_]+=$b[$_],say"$i,$_,".($s[$_]^=1)if$i==$a[$_]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBCsIwFET3PYXUv0hIGn6UrDTewBNIDBFa@FCa0oggpVc3JrqZNzPMzP0ympwZhBuQk/AoEMJx27/CuBvicr6cigIxVAo8X0v42X3gaz15J2x9eSdTeLdAErxsFYNUu7vVnAYga//bbcvZIDYaURpsDgXFNsdKg584PylOKXdXo1Bj7qYv)

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), <s>105</s> <s>87</s> 85 bytes

```
{|t|enum|[([_+_]*(t-_1[0]+1))()|enum|(_+_)]|{[[_+_4,_3,_4//_2%2=0]]if[_4%_2=0]}|sort}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/LasMwEEXX8VcMgoDcqESS7dAY/AHdd6cIYRI5McQPLKWb2N/ujuw@6EKa4Z553Bm6Szk/o00FeQGn@Tn60baPZlRUmZ3RL9S/GqG43ok4pvHKKJJYj08VSlJmEmbS/d7IrSy41nWlTLo1IZ9G1w1@mqcoasq6BdwTBsAIVTeAt86bc@ksgxYuXbTZ9EPdeiBFUcAHQggQCOKdYEBygiX@HIz@tsIeCCx63dhA@nJw9r319moH6s/oPEZ6r6837wJXqIlc0xhNKOX6e@2pYeBsXxBGgvpvAt6p9d8ANE7DJqxDMRxhPy1aXtx/218U3IuOG5ef/NIarliBQNA/3I0S6FpcWFegvpHUoMHe8aqfgqoiwf6la220/tMsOefAmQgh42sSyaCEF6EEKLGMg1wpJCFmPFpaZMKSNINDxo5vcBSSCQkpaofsCw)

Explanation:

```
{|t| /* Declare a lambda with one parameter */
/* The input stream contains arrays */
enum| /* For each array in the input, push an ascending number after it */
/* [1] (for stream content in this point, see below) */
[ /* For each array-number pair in the stream: */
    (
        [_+_] /* Create a copy of the array with the number as the last element */
        *(t-_1[0]+1) /* Create copies of the array for every ms simulated */
    )()| /* Push all copies to the stream */
    enum| /* After each copy, push an ascending number to the stream */
    (_+_) /* Append the number to each array before */
]|
/* [2] (for stream content in this point, see below) */
{
    /* Push an on or off event to the stream: */
    [[
        _+_4,      /* delay + time = actual time */
        _3,        /* light-id */
        _4//_2%2=0 /* does the light go on or off? */
    ]] 
    if[_4%_2=0] /* if the light goes on or off (time%period=0) */
}|
/* [3] (for stream content in this point, see below) */
sort /* Sort the events */
}
```

The stream contains at point `[1]` values in the following order:

```
[delay, period], light-id
 _1[0]  _1[1]    _2
```

The stream contains at point `[2]` values in the following order:

```
delay, period, light-id, time
_1     _2      _3        _4
```

The stream contains at point `[3]` arrays with the following structure:

```
[time, light-id, on_or_off]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 121 bytes

```haskell
import Data.List
t!l=sort$(zip[0..]l)>>=takeWhile(\(a,_,_)->a<=t).(\(i,(d,w))->iterate(\(t,i,s)->(t+w,i,not s))(d,i,2>1))
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##Nco9C4MwEMbx3U9xgkOOXkMUujWZOnbvYEUCBjyML5gDoV/epkO35//jGX2aQoznyfO27gIPL14/OUkhZbQpU6U@vLVG6y6ic1b8FF4jx6DeylNPPV6dv1tBnYFJDXRgJpawe/mdhJhSFiWXI89lFUiI@cfUuBrxnD0vYGFYC4Bt50WggsYYAyW0CsAQ1LmQQN3MP7rzCw)

This is the program I started from:

```haskell
import Data.List

type LightId = Int
type Time = Int
type State = Bool
type LightEvent = (Time, LightId, State)

lightSimulation :: Time -> Time -> [(Time, State)]
lightSimulation delay interval = iterate step (delay, True)
  where step (time, state) = (time+interval, not state)

addId :: LightId -> (Time, State) -> LightEvent
addId id (t, s) = (t, id, s)

simulate :: Time -> [(Time, Time)] -> [LightEvent]
simulate timeLimit lights = sort $ concatMap lightSim (zip [0..] lights)
  where withinTimeLimit = ((<=timeLimit) . fst)
        lightSims (id, (delay, interval)) = map (addId id) $ takeWhile withinTimeLimit (lightSimulation delay interval)
```

And before final golfing I has shortened it to:

```haskell
import Data.List

light (id,(delay,interval)) = iterate step (delay, id, True)
  where step (time, id, state) = (time+interval, id, not state)

simulate timeLimit lights = sort $ concatMap lightSims (zip [0..] lights)
  where lightSims l = takeWhile(\(a,b,c)->a<=timeLimit)$light l
```